# QML Combobox with QSqlModel

Tags: qt, combobox, qml, qsqltablemodel, qsqlquerymodel

I'm currently facing problems with populating a `QML Combobox` with a `QSqlTableModel`.

**Example Database:**

```
  Table Customer                    Table Project
|   id   |   name   |      |   id   |   name  |  fk_customer  | 
|........|..........|      |........|.........|...............|
|    1   |  name1   |      |    1   |  pro1   |      1        |
|    2   |  name2   |      |    2   |  pro2   |      1        |
|    3   |  name3   |      |    3   |  pro3   |      3        |
```

I want to show a form with a `QML Combobox` to select the customer by name.
Therefore I am setting the combobox model to a `QSqlTableModel` with `table="customer"` and `textRole="name"`.

My Problem now resides in setting the `Combobox.currentindex` to the correct value from the database and of course to read the `selected ID` back from the combobox.
The `Comboboxes` documentation states that whenever the combobox is populated with a new model, its current index is set to `1`.
I tried to set the currentindex with `Component.onCompleted` Signal from combobox and its parent but the selected index was always set to `1`.

So I think I might have made conceptional mistake when implementing the model or the `QML-file.`

Does anyone know a suggested way when and how to pre set a QML Combobox with a given value from c++ model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand what the problem is since you do not provide an MCVE, so my response will try to show the correct solution.

Assuming you understand that the `QSqlTableModel` can not be used directly in QML but you have to add roles that correspond to the fields and overwrite the `data()` and `roleNames()` method.

To obtain the information of the given `ID` the `currentIndex` of the view must use the `data()` method of the model so the corresponding `QModelIndex` and the role must be created, in this case to simplify that task I have implemented a function that given the row and the name of the field returns the data.

Using the above I have implemented the following class:

**sqltablemodel.h**

```
#ifndef SQLTABLEMODEL_H
#define SQLTABLEMODEL_H

#include <QSqlTableModel>
#include <QSqlRecord>

class SqlTableModel : public QSqlTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList fieldNames READ fieldNames)
public:
    using QSqlTableModel::QSqlTableModel;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const
    {
       QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
       for (int i = 0; i < record().count(); i ++) {
           roles.insert(Qt::UserRole + i + 1, record().fieldName(i).toUtf8());
       }
       return roles;
   }
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role=Qt::DisplayRole) const
    {
        QVariant value;
        if (index.isValid()) {
            if (role < Qt::UserRole) {
                value = QSqlQueryModel::data(index, role);
            } else {
                int columnIdx = role - Qt::UserRole - 1;
                QModelIndex modelIndex = this->index(index.row(), columnIdx);
                value = QSqlQueryModel::data(modelIndex, Qt::DisplayRole);
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant data(int row, const QString & fieldName){
        int col = record().indexOf(fieldName);
        if(col != -1 && 0 <= row && row < rowCount()){
            QModelIndex ix = index(row, col);
            return ix.data();
        }
        return QVariant();
    }
    QStringList fieldNames() const{
        QStringList names;
        for (int i = 0; i < record().count(); i ++) {
            names << record().fieldName(i);
        }
        return names;
    }
};

#endif // SQLTABLEMODEL_H
```

So you must create the model and export it to QML:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    if(!createConnection()) // open the connection with the DB
        return -1;

    SqlTableModel model;
    model.setTable("Customer");
    model.select();

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("cppmodel", &model);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

And the connection is made in QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 320
    height: 240
    title: qsTr("ComboBox with SqlTableModel")
    ComboBox {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        model: cppmodel
        textRole: "name"
        Component.onCompleted: currentIndex = 4
        onCurrentIndexChanged: {
            var id = cppmodel.data(currentIndex, "id");
            var name = cppmodel.data(currentIndex, "name");
            console.log(qsTr("currentIndex: %1, id: %2, name: %3").arg(currentIndex).arg(id).arg(name))
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/52524574).</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  
I think know what the problem with my code was:  
I was exporting the Model to QML with the qmlRegisterType method, because I thought it might be better to not make all this calls to the database on startup.  
But model: SqlTableModel { table name: "customer" } and Component.onCompleted: { currentIndex = backend.customerIndex }  
always lead to  currentIndex = 1.